# Grails RestfulController not recieving data from rest teamplate on a post (SAVE)

Tags: rest, grails, resttemplate

i have a grails rest interface that extends extends RestfulController.  When i dont override any methods and my code looks like this:

```
class UserController extends RestfulController<User> {

   static responseFormats = ["json"]

    UserController() {
        super(User)
    }
}
```

Wit the above code i can post via resttemplate and via curl without problems

```
_restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, httpEntity, clazz, id)
```

once i override some of the rest controller like the code below my resttemplate.exchange no longer works.  i am not seeing a user object being passed into the controller (checking via debug). Using a curl post i see an object being passed to the controller.  i can successfully use a GET via curl and the restTemplate.echange

```
class UserController extends RestfulController<User> {

    static responseFormats = ["json"]

    UserController() {
        super(User)
    }
    @Transactional
    def save(User user) {
        user.save(flush: true)
        render(model: user, status: 201) as JSON
    }
}
```

my headers and template are built like so:

```
private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    return converters;
}

private HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType((MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return headers;
}

private RestTemplate getTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new CustomResponseErrorHandler());
    return restTemplate;
}
```

the error message i recieve when post from the resttemplate.exchange is:

```
An unexpected error occurredorg.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class receiptbucketserver.User] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
```

any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

ok, not really an answer. i have ZERO idea as to why resttemplate.exchange fails with anything but the default RestfulController code but i was able to steal from restful controller and get what i wanted, which was control and the ability to debug the methods such as save... this is what i stole from super....

```
@Override
Object save() {
    def instance = createResource()
    User user = instance
    user.save(flush: true)
    respond user, [status: CREATED]
}
```